# How to listen to an HTML button through the backend Javascript file?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, backend

I am coding a website with a backend and I would like to add an event listener that listens to a button that is in the ./public/index.html but I can't do getElementById because when I do "node app.js" it says that the document doesn't exist because the html file isn't running?

I tried updating a variable with `onclick` function in HTML and when the server sees that that variable is `true` it fires an event.

EDIT: I have used a post form and in my server, I do app.post("/postRequest")

Comment: Please add some [mre] you question is not clear, and read [ask], respect time other users on this forum

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have achieved this by making a post form:

```
<form action="/request" method="post">
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
 </form>
```

and in server i handle the post request:

```
app.post("/request", (req, res) => {
    res.render("./example.ejs")
  })
```